# ng-init with condition statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5.3

I have a Angular JS  Application,

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-init="getTableData('{{URL::route('get_repair_category')}}')">
```

When Page loading the getTableData will execute, but I want to check a variable **$rootScope.Dealer** and switch the function name of initialization.

Eg : if **$rootScope.Dealer** value present I wanto execute the function named **getDealerData**

And If the value is not set need to execute the **getTableData** function.

How can I make this in anglar js template.

I just tried the ng-if, but its not working...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use simple Javascript syntax in ng-init directive like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-init="Dealer ? getDealerData('{{URL::route('get_repair_category')}}') : getTableData('{{URL::route('get_repair_category')}}')">
```

Here is a plnkr for you (I've changed backend route generation to text):
https://plnkr.co/edit/CJOMT0g50BCWa3j02rcS?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope) {

  $rootScope.dealer = ["a", "b", "c"];

  $scope.getTableData = function(x) {
    return x;
  }
  $scope.getDelearData = function() {
    return $rootScope.dealer;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-init="data = getDelearData() || getTableData('table data')">
    {{data}}
  </div>
</div>
```